# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Script component error

Tags: ssis

I am getting below error in SSIS script component "Object reference not set to an instance of an object Script component error".
The below code i have written in script component.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    //Declare Variables
    String TaskName;
    String ColName;
    Int32 ColLineageID;
    String ColKey;

    //Read the Package File
    XmlDocument PackageFile = new XmlDocument();
    PackageFile.Load(Variables.VarPackagePath);

    //Create Hash Table 
    Hashtable ColKeyTable = new Hashtable();

    XmlNamespaceManager NameSpcMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(PackageFile.NameTable);
    NameSpcMgr.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts");

    foreach (XmlNode childnode in PackageFile.SelectNodes("//*[@lineageId != '' and @name != '']"))
    {
        XmlNode ExecutableNode = childnode.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::DTS:Executable[1]", NameSpcMgr);
        TaskName = ExecutableNode.SelectSingleNode("DTS:Property[@DTS:Name='ObjectName']", NameSpcMgr).InnerText;
        ColName = childnode.Attributes["name"].Value;
        ColLineageID = Convert.ToInt32(childnode.Attributes["lineageId"].Value);
        ColKey = TaskName + ColName + ColLineageID;
        if (!ColKeyTable.ContainsKey(ColKey))
        {
            ColKeyTable.Add(ColKey, DBNull.Value);

            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.ColLineageID = ColLineageID;
            Output0Buffer.ColName = ColName;
            Output0Buffer.TaskName = TaskName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THis error i am getting.   at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows()
   at UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)

Comment: Your trying to set something that is NULL or not created properly

Comment: put in a break point and step through it (F11)

Comment: are all the variables being used in the script have the same name (case) as your checked?